# characteristic equation doubts

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am a newbie in matrix algebra, struggling with some basic concepts:

[image: characteristic equation]

I do not understand from the above matrix(2x2) example:

- How is it possible the above to be true?, multiplying by the identity matrix, means that the position row 2, col 1, will always be 0. And in **A**, the value of row 2, col 1, is 1... Therefore, it will always be $1-0$ regardless of the value of $\lambda$ I choose.
- When I do operations in matrices, ie: A - B. I thought the result was a matrix, (I "loop" through them doing the position to position A - B). So, how come in the above equation it returns a scalar 0? or is 0 a matrix with all 0 values?

I know my reasoning must be wrong somewhere, but not sure where.

Comment: $|A-\lambda I| = \det(A-\lambda I)$

Comment: What is denoted by $|A-\lambda I|$ is the *determinant* of the matrix $A-\lambda I$. It is a scalar, and its nullity means the corresponding homogeneous linear system  has a non-trivial solution.